# Having a mobile device and a windows VM on different locations using same external ip

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vpn

I have a setup as described in the title, a local android mobile device and a windows VM hosted on the cloud.

I need to have the VM's remote ip given by a VPN service (which I'm still to choose, such as ExpreesVPN, NordVPN, etc) but I also need to have the mobile device in my office use the same external ip as if both devices were on the same LAN.

I haven't been able to make any attempets so far, i'm having a litte trouble searching for the basics involved in this kind of setup.

Comment: You can't have two devices on the internet with the same public IP. Well you could but it won't work properly. How would another device know which one to send data to?

Comment: @DavidPostill, I mean to have both devices as if they were on a LAN. Different internal ips, the same external ip.